# windows symbolic file links arn't followed through network access

Tags: windows, share, symlink

I have a server with win7 and a big share on

C:\share

In this share there are many symbolic links to files on other local disks like

C:\share\file.txt(symlink) <-> D:\file.txt

I can access the file over:

C:\share\file.txt

\server\share\file.txt

but if I try to access from an other pc I can't open the file. I'm able to delete, rename ... the link but it seems that the symbolic link isn't processed by the server.

Can I change something with cifs to make this work?

I already checked the acls of the link and the file and set them to allow everybody everything. I also can access the file with d$.

Hope there is a solution...

Answer (score 0):

I found the same thing.  Didn't find a solution and wound up abandoning using symlinks altogether.

Comment: are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

how about dfs its not symbolic links but should accomplish what you want!

Comment: The plan was to build an alternative to dfs or whs but anyway thx for your post